# jQuery issue with alert box

Tags: jquery

The following is not working as expected, it's not picking up the alert message when you click on '.arrow-_down_img'

```
        function slideDown_Menu(){
                    $('.main_nav').slideDown('slow', function(){
                        $('.arrow_down_img').removeClass('arrow_down_img').addClass('arrow_up_img');
                    });
        }

        function slideUp_Menu(){
                    $('.main_nav').slideUp('slow', function(){
                        $('.arrow_up_img').removeClass('arrow_up_img').addClass('arrow_down_img');
                    });
        }

        $('.arrow_down_img').click(function(){
            // evt.preventDefault();
            // slideDown_Menu();
            alert('test');

        });

        $('.arrow_up_img').click(function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            slideUp_Menu();
        });
```

HTML

```
        <div class="arrow_up">
            <div class="arrow_up_img"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: do you have an element with the class .arrow_down_img?

Comment: What does the console tell you?

Comment: Err, you check on 'arrow_down_img' and your div is named 'arrow_up_img'?

Comment: But that class gets removed if you see in the jQuery...

Comment: @Alex: He is commented that line, which replaces class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no element with class of `.arrow_down_img` on DOMReady, you should delegate the event, from one of static parents of the element or document object.

```
$(document).on('click', '.arrow_down_img', function(evt){
    // evt.preventDefault();
    // slideDown_Menu();
    alert('test');
});
```

Also note that in your click handler `evt` is undefined.

Comment: this worked for me, I will accept the answer as soon as it allows me. I still need to get hold of the delegation concept I will do some reading.. Thanks for your help :P